# Тормозит фризы Visual Studio при переключении между экземплярами

Tags: visual-studio, windows-10

Появились какие-то фризы в несколько секунд, когда я находясь в одном экземпляре Visual Studio 2019 я перехожу в другой экземпляр.

ОС: Windows 10

Еще я заметил, что Task Manager перестал обновлять статистику по используемым ресурсам, т.е цифры не меняются с момента его запуска.

Подскажите, куда копать?

Comment: В сторону выгрузки ненужных плагинов. И вообще облегчение VS и увеличение производительности машины самой.

Comment: У меня 16 гигов ОЗУ и CoreI5 последних поколений. Этого должно хватать, если я не нахожусб в состояние дебага чего-то большого

Comment: Приложение приложению рознь. Вы поймите к примеру интелисенс будет работать по разному в большом и маленьком приложении. Попробуйте поотключать плагины и поэкспериментируйте. Включить вы всегда сможете

Comment: @AzizUmarov может быть, но раньше эти же приложения норм работали с Resharper с 2-мя вижуалками.

Comment: А обновления не прилетали в недавнем прошлом. Это же программирование. Если б всё было б замечательно то зачем обновления?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes

Comment: Fix for an intermittent crash in Visual Studio while using WinForms .NET Core designer.
.NET 5.0.1 insertion into Visual Studio v 16.8.3
Fixed an issue where some of the UI context activiated tool windows can cause Visual Studio to crash.
Fixed Push from Manage Branches page when there is no Git remote tracking branch.

Comment: Одно делают другое ломают. Даже читать не хочу

Comment: Вырубил Resharper и фризы прекратились. Вероятно, они что-то в последнем релизе поломали или появилась какая-то фича, которая жрет ресурсы=(

Comment: Что и требовалось доказать